# Trouble on demonstrating irrational exponent rules

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers

As defined, for $x$ irrational and $a\in\mathbb{R}_+^*$, there are $A_1 = \left\{r\in\mathbb{Q} | r<x\right\}; A_2 = \left\{s\in\mathbb{Q} | s>x\right\} \Rightarrow B_1 = \left\{a^r|r\in A_1\right\};  B_2 = \left\{a^s|s\in A_2\right\}$. Basically, since $s - r \to 0$, we have:

1. If $a > 1$, then $r < x < s \Rightarrow a^r < a^x < a^s$;
2. If $0 < a < 1$, then $r < x < s \Rightarrow a^s < a^x < a^r$;

defining $a^x$. Finally, by this definition, if $A < P < B$ and $A < Q < B$, then we have $P = Q$ (same boundaries, having $B - A \to 0$).

To prove $a^{x + y}$ rule is simple.

If $a > 1 \Rightarrow r < x < s \Rightarrow a^r < a^x < a^s; p < y < q\Rightarrow a^p < a^y < a^q$. By definition these stuff are positive, so: $a^ra^p < a^x a^y<a^sa^q \Leftrightarrow a^{r+p}<a^xa^y<a^{s+q}$. In other hand, $r < x < s$ and $p < y < q \Rightarrow r + p < x + y < s + q \Rightarrow a^{r + p} < a^{x + y} < a^{s + q}$. Both of them have same boudaries, so $a^{x + y} = a^xa^y$. Something similar goes for $0 < a < 1$.

So $1 := a^0 = a^{x +(- x)} = a^{x}a^{-x} \therefore a^{-x} := \dfrac{1}{a^x}$. And there goes $a^{x - y}$ rule: $a^{x - y} = a^{x + (-y)} = a^{x}a^{-y} = a^{x}\dfrac{1}{a^y} = \dfrac{a^x}{a^y}$.

Now suppose $a,b > 1$. Then, $r < x < s \Rightarrow a^r < a^x < a^s; b^r < b^x < b^s \Rightarrow a^rb^r < a^xb^x < a^sb^s \Leftrightarrow (ab)^r < a^xb^x < (ab)^s$. In other hand, $c = ab > 1$, so $c^r < c^x < c^s \Leftrightarrow (ab)^r < (ab)^x < (ab)^s$. Hence $(ab)^x = a^xb^x$. Something similar happens to $0 < a,b < 1$.

The whole problem is when we try to show $(ab)^x = a^xb^x$ for $a > 1$ and $0 < b < 1$. How to show it is also valid in this case?

Comment: What has been the whole problem, in this case? You might consider using limit rules and looking at a proof of the "product-of-limits-is-limit-of-products" theorem

Comment: Not to nitpick, but we you say "we have 1) 2) defining $a^x$" in what way does that define $a^x$.  Is $a^x$ equal to $\sup B_1$?  equal to $\inf B_2$.  Somehow the sets $B_1, B_2$ themselves?  The Dedikind cut $B_1$?  What is $\mathbb R^*_+$?

Comment: @FShrike Trying the same way of the others: $a^r < a^x < a^s$ and $b^s < b^x < b^r \Rightarrow a^rb^s < a^xb^x < a^sb^r$. None of those boundaries would appear using $c = ab$.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah, it's the idea of Dedekind cut. For $a > 1$, for example, each element of $B_1$ is smaller than one from $B_2$. You could also think of it as a sequence, having $r_n < r{n + 1} < x < s_{n + 1} < s_n$. There is one real value that is greater than all of $a^r$ and smaller than all of $a^s$. This one is $a^x$. There is, of course, a huge chance I'm being 0% formal. It happens.

Comment: I found, when trying to do the equivalent of the problem (Baby Rudin. chapter 2 problem 6) that I had to prove that there is no ration $q$ and no positive $e > 0$ so that $b^q = M$ but for all $r\in \mathbb Q; r > q$ that $b^r \ge M+e$ (assuming $b > 1$). That was easy to prove by contradiction and with it the result followed.